# The approach to solving this limit is confusing me.

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to handle the different scenarios you might encounter when evaluating limits. My confusion starts with the diagram below that was provided in my Calc class:

[Flow chart of a step-by-step procedure to solving limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uujNI.jpg)

In the case that you simplify the limit to the form $\frac{A}{0}$, you would then evaluate both sides of the limit to see if the limit equals $\infty$ or $-\infty$ or does not exist. But, for the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 4/3} \frac{3x^2-4x}{|3x-4|}$$

Plugging in the limiting value of $\frac{4}{3}$ will give the indeterminate form of $\frac{0}{0}$. In this scenario, I was directed by the flowchart to try to simplify this limit algebraically which didn't work.

Trying the question on Symbolab, the solution was to compare the left and right-sided limits to see if they were equal (they weren't and the limit does not exist). This doesn't make sense to me.

I thought you only evaluate the left and right-sided limits of a limit only if the original limit was in the form $\frac{A}{0}$, but in my case, it was in the form $\frac{0}{0}$.

Now I'm so confused as to how to approach the different cases of limits. When do you compare the sided limits? When do you factorize or rationalize?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: There is no step-by-step formula to evaluate limits. There is only a series of tools that you learn to use effectively, by experience doing many examples.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please make posts using TeX typesetting.

Comment: You always CAN investigate a limit as $x\to a$ ($a$ is a real number, not $\pm\infty$) by looking at each side separately.  But in many cases, the only result of this will be that you do twice the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use rules; use your head.

$$
{3x^2-4x\over|3x-4|}=x{3x-4\over|3x-4|}
$$
The factor of $x$ is harmless;
$$
\lim_{x\to4/3}x{3x-4\over|3x-4|}={4\over3}\lim_{x\to4/3}{3x-4\over|3x-4|}
$$
Now that fraction is $-1$ for $x<4/3$, and it's $+1$ for $x>4/3$, so there's clearly no limit as $x\to4/3$.

Comment: That makes more sense. But how would you know to compare the side limits from the start? Is there some sort of indicator or is it just experience? My professor strictly used this flowchart to solve questions during class so that's why I was so confused.

Comment: The "tip-off" is the absolute value.  Because to get a simpler formula for $|a|$, you have to consider $a\ge0$ and $a<0$ separately.

Comment: Experience (at least, in my case). I know what $x/|x|$ looks like, and this is just a simple variation on that theme.